# How to print informative error message in a vectored exception handler?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm writing a command-line C++ program on Windows, that inevitably sometimes hits an error such as a stack overflow or access violation; in these cases, I would like it to print an informative error message before exiting. This is what I have at the moment:

```
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0, handler);
```

and

```
LONG WINAPI handler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) {
  if (ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode ==
      EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW) {
    puts("stack overflow");
    ExitProcess(1);
  }
  printf("exception %X", ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode);
  ExitProcess(1);
}
```

The special case for stack overflow is because I have found that `puts` works in that situation but `printf` doesn't. Is that because there is so little stack space left that only the simplest functions work, or because the stack is damaged in such a way that varargs doesn't work?

Right now, I'm getting exception C0000005. I look at the definitions in `minwinbase.h` and `ntstatus.h` and find this is `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. Which is useful to know! It would be even better if I could get more details as well as doing the lookup automatically. I notice the accompanying comment in the header file says

```
// MessageText:
//
// The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.
```

A format string, which suggests this information could be automatically printed. What's the way to do this?

Minimal, complete and verifiable example, compile with `cl main.cc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LONG WINAPI handler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo) {
  if (ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode ==
      EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW) {
    puts("stack overflow");
    ExitProcess(1);
  }
  printf("exception %X\n", ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode);
  ExitProcess(1);
}

void overflow() { overflow(); }

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  AddVectoredExceptionHandler(0, handler);

  // demonstrate access violation
  *(int *)0 = 0;

  // demonstrate stack overflow
  overflow();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Don't do anything in your exception handler. Simply call [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump) for offline analysis. A user will not understand what a stack overflow or an access violation is. And there is **nothing** they can do about it either, so why tell them?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Done.

Comment: @IInspectable Among other things, this is so I can tell users 'the program crashed? Okay, please copy and paste the error message it printed, and send to me.'

Comment: If you need to let your users know, tell them that *"The process entered an unrecoverable state and needs to terminate."* You don't need `printf` for that. Of course you could also configure Windows Error Reporting to do all that for you, including the mini dump. If your users tell you, that your program raised an access violation, what are you going to do with that information to diagnose the issue? That's just way too little data to sustain a successful support strategy.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, the ideal would be if I could get stack tracing to work in the vectored exception handler, so the user could send the full stack trace in plain text format. The mini dump would be what, a binary blob that one hopes the Visual Studio debugger can do something with? I can see the merits of trying that, but worth at least trying for a simpler/more reliable solution first.

Comment: Let the user send the minidump file to you. Yes, you load it into your VS IDE and debug your app with it. It has the information you need. A stack trace won't tell you the actual state your app was in at the time of the crash.  Only the chain of function calls leading up to the crash.

Comment: To gather a stack trace with symbols on the client machine, you will have to ship debug symbols (.pdb files). That's generally not desirable, nor required. A mini dump will gather the required information on the client machine without the need for symbol data. A mini dump uses a proprietary file format, that can be opened in *any* Windows debugger. Microsoft provides a public API for reading mini dumps ([Debug Help Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/debug-help-library)), in case you need that.

Comment: If you are looking for a simple and reliable option, [Windows Error Reporting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/windows-error-reporting) is for you. Setting it up amounts to writing a few keys to the registry. Everything else is done for you. No exception filters required in your client code, nor any code to write the crashdump, unless you have specific requirements to control the size and contents of the mini dump file. If it fits your specific needs, Microsoft can collect the dumps for you, analyze them, and have users notified about fixes that apply to *their* issues.